# How to get Jenkins display TAP output from perlcritic

Tags: perl, jenkins, tap

Here is the command and stdout captured:

```
$perlcritic --gentle . | nl -nln | sed 's/\(.*source OK\)$/ok \1/' | sed '/source OK$/!s/^.*$/not ok &/' | tee perlcritic_tap.results.1
```

output:

```
not ok 1        Bareword file handle opened at line 184, column 17.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 2        Two-argument "open" used at line 184, column 17.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 3        Bareword file handle opened at line 311, column 9.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 4        Two-argument "open" used at line 311, column 9.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 5        Bareword file handle opened at line 371, column 12.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 6        Two-argument "open" used at line 371, column 12.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 7        Bareword file handle opened at line 390, column 13.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 8        Two-argument "open" used at line 390, column 13.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 9        Bareword file handle opened at line 522, column 5.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 10       Two-argument "open" used at line 522, column 5.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 11       Bareword file handle opened at line 615, column 10.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 12       Two-argument "open" used at line 615, column 10.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
```

Verify the file contents:

```
more perlcritic_tap.results.1 

not ok 1        Bareword file handle opened at line 184, column 17.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 2        Two-argument "open" used at line 184, column 17.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 3        Bareword file handle opened at line 311, column 9.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 4        Two-argument "open" used at line 311, column 9.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 5        Bareword file handle opened at line 371, column 12.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 6        Two-argument "open" used at line 371, column 12.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 7        Bareword file handle opened at line 390, column 13.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 8        Two-argument "open" used at line 390, column 13.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 9        Bareword file handle opened at line 522, column 5.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 10       Two-argument "open" used at line 522, column 5.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 11       Bareword file handle opened at line 615, column 10.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 12       Two-argument "open" used at line 615, column 10.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
```

Now append the top portion of TAP format:

```
echo 1.. `wc -l < perlcritic_tap.results.1` | cat - perlcritic_tap.results.1  > perlcritic_tap.results
```

perlcritic_tap.results:

```
1.. 12
not ok 1        Bareword file handle opened at line 184, column 17.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 2        Two-argument "open" used at line 184, column 17.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 3        Bareword file handle opened at line 311, column 9.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 4        Two-argument "open" used at line 311, column 9.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 5        Bareword file handle opened at line 371, column 12.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 6        Two-argument "open" used at line 371, column 12.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 7        Bareword file handle opened at line 390, column 13.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 8        Two-argument "open" used at line 390, column 13.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 9        Bareword file handle opened at line 522, column 5.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 10       Two-argument "open" used at line 522, column 5.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 11       Bareword file handle opened at line 615, column 10.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
not ok 12       Two-argument "open" used at line 615, column 10.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
```

But i still cannot get Jenkins to recognize the TAP file format, and i get an error:

```
Found matching files but did not find any TAP results.
```

Comment: Have you tried `Test::Perl::Critic`?

Comment: Have you tried removing portions of the output lines to determine if any of the characters ( such as ,.:()" ) are getting in the way?

Comment: Excellent suggestions, i will try both

Comment: tried Test::Perl::Critic  it has some good features, like Displaying line numbers where violations occur, but the output format is where the problem lies because Jenkins needs to consume this, PLUS Jenkins TAP plugin does not group tests (seems to be TAP limitation as per the plugin author) so i am back to square one

Comment: @CraigTreptow
Not sure how can i remove ...(Severity: ) i am guessing add another sed with regex ? perhaps

Comment: @kamal - I was just thinking manually before Jenkins tries to read it until you know for sure that is the problem, then some other solution may present itself.

Comment: I think i found the problem, as per http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/Test-Harness-2.64/lib/Test/Harness/TAP.pod#The_plan there is no space before N in  1..N, which IS the PLAN

Comment: You can use the `--verbose` flag to govern what perlcritic will output. Try it with `--verbose 3` and it shouldn't have any of the characters mentioned above.

Comment: well, even when i have a perfect TAP result, the plugin still complains, and i checked with and without ...(), i can still get Valid TAP result , you can just paste the TAP results @ http://instanttap.appspot.com/ and verify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in the plug-in. It looks for *.tap, even though you specified a different file extension (the plug-in developer probably was drunk when he wrote that code). I've filled [an issue for this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15586), but you can have your results working in the current version (1.6) of TAP plug-in doing the following:

1) as you mentioned, remove the space in the TAP plan (i.e.: 1..12 rather than 1.. 12).,

2) instead of writing perlcritic_tap.results, use perlcritic_tap.tap.

I'm preparing a patch for this and will cut a release in few hours. It takes a while before the update site is synced in Jenkins, but hopefully by Monday at work you should be able to use the plug-in with no problem.

Let me know if you need anything. I'm quite new here, and don't have Karma enough to add more links, but I've attached some screen shots of the plug-in using your TAP file to the issue in Jenkins JIRA ;-)

All the best, -kinow

Comment: perlcritic --gentle cgi-bin/cr/ | tee pc.out worked, plus i used Violations Plugin for Jenkins

Answer (score 3):

I think it is the extra space in your plan.
Try 1..12 instead.  (No space after the ..)

I've used the Jenkins JUnit plugin with:

prove --formatter=TAP::Formatter::JUnit

Comment: I realized the mistake and corrected it, but that did not resolve the issue. Good Catch BTW

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with the [JUnit TAP harness](https://metacpan.org/module/TAP%3a%3aHarness%3a%3aJUnit) when getting tests into Jenkins. The latest version allows you to group tests into packages via environment-variables too.

```
export JUNIT_OUTPUT_FILE="$WORKSPACE/junit_app.xml"
export JUNIT_PACKAGE="app"
cd $WORKSPACE/Offer; prove -I ./lib -v --harness=TAP::Harness::JUnit
```

The maintainers seem responsive (the package env-var was a small patch I implemented) so if there are any limitations you should be able to correct them.

Comment: So you used Perl::Critic with TAP::Harness::JUnit to get the XML output ? Since i dont have unit tests, i only want to run Perl::Critic against Perl code

Comment: No, just with standard tests, but it seems to translates TAP to JUnit just fine, and does the grouping of tests.